# How to count last names in a table without duplicating employee ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, distinct

I have an employee table with duplicate instances of employees. For instance the last name Baba may show up 2 times with the same employee ID. I have to count last names from the table, but do not want to count the same one twice.

I am writing SQL in Postgres. Here is the table from which I draw my query:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    emp_no int   NOT NULL,
    birth_date date   NOT NULL,
    first_name varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
    gender varchar(100)   NOT NULL,
    hire_date date   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Salaries PRIMARY KEY (
        emp_no
     )
);
```

The data was given and contained duplicates. I cannot remove the duplicates but do not want to count them. Here is my query statement:

```
SELECT Employee.last_name, COUNT(Employee.last_name) AS "Last Name Count"
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Employee.last_name
ORDER BY "Last Name Count" DESC;
```

The output works well but I am sure it is counting some last names more than once. 
I have tried adding a WHERE cause to get a count of last names where the emp_no is distinct but it does not work.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Please add a few rows of sample data, and the expected result.

Comment: Why are you "sure it is counting some last names more than once"?

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure it is counting the same person twice. I am assuming it is because I am asking for a count on last names and one person may show up more than one time (in name) but have only one employee ID. Therefore I do not want that person's last name counted more than one time.

Comment: First off your description does not match the table definition, You mention employee Id, but that column does not exist. I'll assume that is a typo and you mean emp_no. In that case the situation you describe "one person may show up more than one time (in name) but have only one" emp_no **cannot** happen. That would require the same emp_no in two rows which cannot happen as emp_no is defined as the PK and is therefore unique in the table. You need to look at other columns to determine if the individual is duplicated; like first name and birth date.

Answer (score 1):

You want to count last names from the table, but do not count the same one twice.
So try this :

```
"SELECT Employee.last_name, COUNT(DISTINCT Employee.last_name) AS "Last Name Count" FROM Employee GROUP BY Employee.last_name"
```

Comment: Thank you, that gave me a total count of 1638

Comment: Yes without duplicates

Answer (score 0):

The emp_no is a primary key, so it has to be unique and a where clause with distinct would have no impact.  The query seems to be accurate, I'd be surprised if it's counting last names more than once.

Comment: `emp_no` is not the case for duplication but `last_name`.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: And the “group by” that was in the initial query handled that need perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just use `distinct` keyword during applying the `COUNT()` aggregation :

```
SELECT e.last_name, COUNT(distinct e.last_name) AS "Last Name Count"
  FROM Employee e
 GROUP BY e.last_name
 ORDER BY "Last Name Count" DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you., that returned a one for each last name.

Answer (score 0):

You should try validating if the first name is counted uniquely by each last name

something like this

```
SELECT Employee.last_name, COUNT(distinct Employee.first_name) AS "Last Name Count"
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Employee.last_name
ORDER BY "Last Name Count" DESC;
```

see fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0a9568e6cb5fb5e0247d2f2c5e95114

or if necessary check if more data is repeating in both lines, doing something like

```
select distinct * from (
SELECT Employee.last_name, 
COUNT(*) over (partition by first_name, birth_date, last_name, gender) AS n
FROM Employee
) V
where n > 1
```

see the fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=223143f0d603abf30d99ad87fa07781e

Comment: That did return a new number, problem is some employees have the same first name and last name with a different employee number. In other words they are different people with the same name. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @Cmac in the second query of my answer you can add all columns that is required to detect a duplicated registry

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your quick responses. They were all very good and helpful!

I ran the following code to find that I was wrong and each individual had only one instance in the table and had only one unique employee ID (emp_no).

SELECT Employee.emp_no, COUNT(Employee.emp_no) AS "Employee ID Count"
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Employee.emp_no
ORDER BY "Employee ID Count" ASC;

Again, thank you all very much!